# Is it ok to have repeated values in some of the columns and similar columns in two separate tables?

Tags: database-design, schema, erd, duplication

I'm trying to create database in which I could store thousands of job postings. I put here 3 sample records of these job postings so that you could better understand how everything looks like:
[image]

Every row is a separate job posting.

Now, based on above data, I've created simple relational database schema filled with this data:
[image]

I have two questions here:

1. `Job posting` table contains column `experience` and `Skills` table contains column named `level`. These two columns have different names but actually contains same repeated values: `trainee`, `junior`, `mid`, `senior`, `expert`. Is this ok to have virtually same columns in two different tables?
2. Repeated values in cells occur almost in every column. For example when you take a look at `title` column in `Job posting` table you'll see that there are two cells with `Python Developer` value. The same story happens in `skill name` column in `Skills` table where you can find two `Python` values. I have thousands of job postings which means that there will be thousands repetitions in columns. Should I do something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the point of creating separate tables for Job title and Skills?

> To be honest I expected that you might propose this kind of solutions i.e creating junction table and I'm not happy with it mostly because I don't get it what I would gain with it.

Without repeating the same answer a third time, I figured I'd address your main question here that for some reason no one else wanted to go into detail about.

What the other answers mentioned by creating additional tables to hold the unique list of repeated entity values, and referencing those values by their immutable keys in the other tables, such as `Skill Names`, is called normalization. It's like a type of refactoring for your data. The reason you would do it is to eliminate the repeated values in your data, which are liable to change.

An integral benefit of data normalization is improved data integrity. Let's say one day the data needs to be updated for the `Skill Name`, from `Rest API` to `RESTful API`. With your current design you would need to update multiple rows to ensure you correctly made the aforementioned data change. Either through user error, or programmatic error (if for some reason the change was made in batches in a non-transactional loop, for example), could leave your data in an intermittent incorrect state.

In a normalized design, where the value of `Rest API` only lives in a single row in a unique table, then you would only need to update that one row, guaranteeing the change was made correctly. Changing a single row is implicitly automic, meaning all or nothing, it's not possible to end up with an intermittent state of the data. It is an improved design for data integrity.

Another secondary benefit of data normalization, is improved performance for such data manipulation changes, since you're only changing a single row as opposed to many rows. And that single row lives in a potentially less transactional table, therefore eliminating what would've caused blocking on the other table.

Answer (score 1):

1
I think it is ok since both columns have a different meaning (job level vs skill level).

2
You could create Skill and Job Title tables.

There is a pitfall to all this. Job posting writers can choose the terms they use for job titles, skills, and levels. If you want to compare jobs from different companies, that's a problem.

Comment: What is the point of creating separate tables for Job title and Skills? How would this relationaI database look like?  I mean if I assume correctly the first one would contain only two columns: ID and title and the second one ID and skill name. And what to do with the rest of the columns these both tables contain (In Job posting this is an experience column and in Skills table this is level and isrequired)?

Answer (score 1):

I would have created a many-to-many relationship instead of your one-to-many. For this you would need a table in between `Job Posting` and `Skill`, let's call it `Job Posting Skills`. This table will then have two foreign keys: one referencing `Job Postings` and one referencing `Skill`. This table can also have the `Level` and `is_required` columns that you have currently in the `Skills` table.

1. If they truly are the same values and will always be so, then it would be better to normalise and put those values in an `Experience` table that you can reference with foreign keys from the two other tables.
2. You could do "something", but this might restrict what those entering the data is able to write. Or in the very least suggest existing values to them before they enter something new. Make it hard to enter something new, but ready to re-use existing values.

Comment: To be honest I expected that you might propose this kind of solutions i.e creating junction table and I'm not happy with it mostly because I don't get it what I would gain with it. In my opinion it would only complicate things more. Could you explain me what is the point of doing this in your way? Is this only a matter of architecture i.e 1 job posting can have many skills and 1 skill can belong to many job posting (many-to-many relationship as you explained it) OR maybe it has something to do with these skill repetitions I mentioned about in my original question?

Comment: @beginsql This is about normalisation, and the benefits are explained in J.D. answer.